# Video reproduction problem

Tags: 11.10, unity, video, graphics

I can't understand why when I reproduce a SD or HD video in Unity the image starts to split horizontally and stutters on panoramas, but I have a perfect image in gnome 3!!!
Can anybody resolve this because I love Unity!

Oneiric 11.10 on Biostar TZ68A+,
Intel i5 3.3 Ghz, 8Gb ram, Nvidia GT520

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, by "reproduce" do you mean "play"? As in, watch the video?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).